# how to get row indices where row slice contains a single value (0)

Tags: numpy

With the numpy array
arr = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]])

I would like to get the indices of all rows where the row slice 2:5 contains all zeros.

In the above example, it should return rows 0 and 2.

I tried:

zero_indices = np.where(not np.any(arr[:,2:5]))

but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm trying to do this over a large array with several million rows.

Comment: Look at `arr[:, 2:5]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
np.nonzero((~arr[:,2:5].astype(bool)).all(1))[0]

Out[133]: array([0, 2], dtype=int32)
```

Or

```
np.nonzero((arr[:,2:5] == 0).all(1))[0]

Out[139]: array([0, 2], dtype=int32)
```